# Why does the accepted answer not come first?

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, sorting

On the question *[Unity Project doesn't have solution file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094908/unity-project-doesnt-have-solution-file)*, if you sort by "votes" or "active", the accepted answer (with the green checkmark) is not the top answer. (At least, this is what I am seeing in my browser.)

This is the only place I've seen this happen, and it seems to go against the standard for Stack Overflow.

Is this a bug?  If not, what is going on?